# Configuring jQuery UI datepicker for name day selection (do not show the year in the datepicker)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

One of my project's requirements is to keep users' name days. For those who don't know what a name day is - a quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_day): "A name day is a tradition in many countries in Europe and Latin America that consists of celebrating the day of the year associated with one's given name."

Basically, the idea is to store only the day and month, the year is irrelevant since a person's name day occurs every year. In the database I'm using the DATE type, without displaying the year part in any views.

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker to select dates in my application. Is there a way to configure the datepicker to somehow ommit year selection? For example - set it to current year and don't display the year at all?

I don't want to modify the datepicker's code and I also like the rest of my datepickers to work and look properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker( { changeYear: false, dateFormat: 'dd/mm', });
```

and then hide the year with CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-year{
    display: none;
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLtS4/

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea but this CSS selector will hide years in all of my datepickers. Since most of my html is generated dynamically by jQuery, I'll just hide the year by the .css method. Thanks.

Comment: you could put a div around that particular datepicker and then hide only the year in that instance: `#yourDiv .ui-datepicker-year{
    display: none;
}`